# Install a new package

Tags: ros, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I use ROS electric and I like to install a new package, for example the navigation package, so that I can use the map_server from this package.

Is there something to adhere when I install this?

Because I install it, but when I try to run the launch file, I get the message that the map_server node could not be found.

Thank you for help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58125/install-a-new-package/) by [JaRu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3620/jaru/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2013-03-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.
As you noticed, first you need to install it from its repository.

```
sudo apt-get install ros-%YOUR_ROS_DISTRO%-navigation
```

Anyway it is already installed by default.
Then you should install the tutorials for that package:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-%YOUR_ROS_DISTRO%-navigation-tutorials
```

then go to that directory, and execute a node:

```
roscd navigation_tutorials
rosrun robot_setup_tf_tutorial tf_broadcaster
```

In another terminal roscd again to that package and:

```
rosrun robot_setup_tf_tutorial tf_listener
```

---

If you want to make that package by yourself, you should go to your workspace directory, and create a package, then create the two .cpp files, modify the CMakeLists.txt and rosmake.

Hope this helps.

Please consult these links for further information:
[TF Setup](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/TF)
[Navigation Package](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation)

---

Originally posted by [aimc](https://answers.ros.org/users/3966/aimc/) with karma: 216 on 2013-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1